Garden-Fi mobile testing
Is there a way to get Garden-Fi application .ipa and .apk files for testing?
Simulated/emulated devices don't have app store and even on real devices accessed remotely it would be best to have binary file to upload, particularly when doing automation.

I understand the issue here, however, at this time we don't have any plans to make the application files (.ipa and .apk files) downloadable.
